# Pattern matching in file or string

Tags: java, pattern-matching

I have been working on a program which amongst other things will search for repeating patterns within a string.
Finding and counting the matches for each pattern type is the easy part and I can sort from the highest scoring to the lowest scoring based on number of matches found. 
Choosing which of the overlapping matches to keep is a bit more difficult, should i remove the leftmost or rightmost?

Lets say I keep the first match found and remove the right most overlapping one and so on. The issue arises when I move on to the next pattern type and find that it would been better to instead remove the leftmost match from the pattern type per above. This would have allowed this this pattern to fit into the space, etc.. 
However again when I get to the next set of patterns, it could transpire that leaving things as they were the first time would benefit,etc...

This swinging to and fro could repeat for the entire file.

My question is: are there any algorithms or techniques to calculate best fit for every single pattern while maintaining the most repeated patterns at the top of the list?

Any advice would be much appreciated ;)
Ed

Comment: What code have you written?

Answer (score 0):

Try to show an example

The only thing that you should do would be (in my opinion):

-Instead of erasing the most-left or most-right, try to save them all, and after analyzing all the matches you should decide what to do. Deleting without certainty is not a good option.